# Material-ui Icon doesn't show theme palette color from current context

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui, lerna

Is not printing the right color because is not receiving custom theme props, but default ones.
Using material-ui version 5.

Already setup theme file with custom properties:
theme.js

```js
const darkTheme = createTheme({
  ...baseTheme,
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
    background: {
      default: '#0D1015',
      paper: '#0D1015'
    },
    primary: {
      main: '#EF7560'
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#1D232E'
    },
    contrastThreshold: 3,
    tonalOffset: 0.2
  }
});
```

And conected to `ThemeProvider` like this
index.js

```js
<StrictMode>
    <RelayEnvironmentProvider environment={RelayEnvironment}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Suspense fallback={<SuspenseFallback header />}>
          <Router>
            <HelmetProvider>
              <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={ErrorFallback}>
                <App />
              </ErrorBoundary>
            </HelmetProvider>
          </Router>
        </Suspense>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </RelayEnvironmentProvider>
  </StrictMode>
```

The theme is setup to dark mode and it's working as expected.
Detailed problem

Sidebar.js

```js
const Sidebar = ({children, pathname}: ISidebarProps) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  console.log('theme =>', theme.palette.primary.main);
...
```

here theme is printing #EF7560 so it's ok, is comming from context as desired.

inside Sidebar render there is an Item

```js
...js
 <List>
          <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <InboxIcon color="primary" />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
          </ListItem>
...
```

As I'm passing color="primary" is expected to see icon with #EF7560 color but instead has the blue default one, as you can see in the image below.
[image]

I can't get the point, why is not receiving the right theme on List item?

Thanks in advance, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: does this work `<InboxIcon color={theme.palette.primary.main} />` ?

Comment: Please add your import code. Where do you import `ThemeProvider`, `createTheme`, and other MUI components? Codesandbox looks fine [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basiclist-material-demo-forked-k2kxs?file=/demo.js)

Comment: @cmgchess it complains about types, is expecting one of "primary", "secondary" and so on.

Comment: @NearHuscarl I'm only importing it on main index.js where wraps the entire app. `import {ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material/styles';` All components are imported from `@mui/material`

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia can you put it in codesandbox, I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: @NearHuscarl, thx for yout time. Already updated codesandbox. It's working on it but not on my site. I can't believe it yet, it's the same code, copy & paste from code to codesandbox. Works on codesandbox and not on the local project. :(

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia search for `1976d2` or `blue[700]` to see if you set it anywhere in your project. Also try creating a brand new project on local and see if the bug still occurs.

Comment: Finally found why... I got installed another dependencie that was using another instance of material. Just removen from package.json works as expected. Thx a lot for your help, very appreciated.

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia what kind of bizarre package is this?

Comment: Still stuck there, I cloned repo outside the monorepo ans it's working. Looks like is something related to lerna monorepo? is also nohoisted from the main and nothing. :(